# find_each in rails with a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to understand the Active Record find_each method to retrieve records in batches.

If a Post has_many comments (thousands of comments) and I want to render each comment, I can do:

@post.comments.each { |comment| ... }

But is it faster if I do :

@post.comments.find_each { |comment| ... } ?

Is the second query valid?

The way I'm seeing this is that by doing @post.comments before the find_each is already getting all the comments for each post so ending the query with find_each is probably redundant ?!

This is the full block of code in a rails app views folder:

```
 json.comments @post.comments.find_each do |comment|
   json.rating comment.rating
   json.content comment.content
 end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@post.comments.find_each` is correct. When you call `@post.comments` the query that it creates does not execute right away. That's why you can chain other query methods like *where* and *order* etc. to this association. (sql log truncated for readability)

```rb
>> comments = Post.first.comments; nil;
  Post Load (0.8ms)
=> nil

# NOTE: ^ no comments are loaded yet, until we need to output the result 

>> comments
  Comment Load (2.0ms)
=> [#<Comment:0x00007f2ef1733328 id: 1, post_id: 1>, ...]  # <= array of 2000 comments
```

When `each` method is chained, all of the comments are loaded into memory which is an issue when you have thousands of records.

```rb
>> Post.first.comments.each{|c| print "." }
  Post Load (0.6ms) 

# NOTE: executes one query for comments
  Comment Load (1.4ms)
.................................................. # <= 2000 dots
=> [#<Comment:0x00007f2ef1560be0 id: 1, post_id: 1>, ...]
```

When `find_each` method is chained, comments are retrieved in batches of 1000 by default:

```rb
>> Post.first.comments.find_each{|c| print "." }
  Post Load (0.6ms)

# NOTE: executes query to get 1000 comments at a time 

  Comment Load (0.8ms)
.................................................. # <= 1000 dots
  Comment Load (0.8ms)
.................................................. # <= 1000 dots
  Comment Load (0.4ms)
# no more comments
=> nil
```

You can also specify the `:batch_size`:

```rb
>> Post.first.comments.find_each(batch_size: 100){|c| print "." }
  Post Load (0.7ms)

# NOTE: get comments in batches of 100

  Comment Load (0.6ms)
.................................................. # <= 100 dots
  Comment Load (0.5ms)
.................................................. # <= 100 dots
# 21 queries in total
=> nil
```

---

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each*